# How to remove olive oil stains from cotton/wool cloths?

Tags: cleaning, olive-oil

I think any cook have came across these nasty stains. What is the best home method of removing them from cotton/wool cloths? I know that the best method is to act proactive and wear protective clothing, but this has happened by accident after the meal was ready.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with using detergent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A surprisingly good way to remove oil stains (even that have set in and gone through the dryer) is using dish soap.  Rub it in, let it sit for a bit, and then wash it out.

Answer (score 0):

Dawn dish detergent works really well, even if it has been through the dryer already! After all it's what they use to get oil off of animals after oil slicks. The best non-homemade remedy i have found is Soil Love, a miracle worker on grease spots!

Comment: Is that product available in the OP country?